# Как создать экземпляр класса который находится в другом файле используя TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Доброго времени суток, Стэковерфлоучане, пробую использовать TypeScript в своём Asp.Net MVC  4 приложении, в одном фале я определил класс

```
class Notice{ 
   public title:string;
   public description: string;
}
```

В другом файле пытаюсь создать экземпляр этого класса, при этом вверху добавив следующуй строчку:

```
/// <reference path="../scr/app.ts"/>
```

А сам экземпляр создаю вот так:

```
 var notice: Notice = new Notice();
```

На выходе получаю ошибку о том что **Notice** is no defined,
я пробовал подключать файл и на самой странице через `<script src="..`, но все равно получаю одну и ту же ошибку, помогите пожалуйста разобраться, заранее всем спасибо за ответы!

Comment: где получается данная ошибка?

Comment: @Grundy ой, забыл указать, прошу прощения. Ошибка возникает в консоли браузера.

Comment: а на страницу ты что подключаешь и как?

Comment: @Grundy а на страницу подключаю через тег <script arc="createConyroller.js"></script> в этом файле создаю экземпляр, так же пробовал добавлять тот файл где хранится класс от которого создаю экземпляр.